# NullPointerException on trying to save SparceBooleanArray

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

Here's the code of my baseadapter which shows contacts' name, phone number and checkboxes alongside them.

```
class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener
{   public SparseBooleanArray mCheckStates;
    LayoutInflater mInflater;
    TextView tv1,tv;
    CheckBox cb;
    int mPos;
    MyAdapter()
    {
        if (mCheckStates==null){
        mCheckStates = new SparseBooleanArray(name1.size());
        }else {
        mCheckStates = (SparseBooleanArray) bundle.getParcelable("myBooleanArray");

        }
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) ContactActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return name1.size();
    }

    public void setPosition(int p){
        mPos = p;
    }

    public int getPosition(){
        return mPos;
    }


    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
        vi = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        tv= (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv1= (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        cb = (CheckBox) vi.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        tv.setText("Name :"+ name1.get(position));
        tv1.setText("Phone No :"+ phno1.get(position));
        cb.setTag(position);
        cb.setChecked(mCheckStates.get(position, false));
        setPosition(position);
        cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

        return vi;
    }
    public boolean isChecked(int position) {
        return mCheckStates.get(position, false);
    }

    public void setChecked(int position, boolean isChecked) {
        mCheckStates.put(position, isChecked);
    }

    public void toggle(int position) {
        setChecked(position, !isChecked(position));
    }
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        mCheckStates.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), isChecked);
    }
}
```

Activity code:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    bundle.putParcelable("myBooleanArray", new SparseBooleanArrayParcelable(adapter.mCheckStates)); 
    //adapter is the MyAdapter object created in parent class
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Note that I'm using `bundle.putParcelable("myBooleanArray", new SparseBooleanArrayParcelable(adapter.mCheckStates));` and `mCheckStates = (SparseBooleanArray) bundle.getParcelable("myBooleanArray");`, to store and retrieve the SparseBooleanArray on activity being destroyed and recreated. The onDestroy() method is of the parent class, which is an activity. I haven't pasted that, because I thought it was irrelevant. Please ask if it's needed.

I'm also using a `SparseBooleanArrayParcelable` class that helps me `mCheckStates` on destruction, and retrieve on creation.

According to the logs, the NullPointerException occurs within onDestroy() when trying to execute `bundle.putParcelable("myBooleanArray", new SparseBooleanArrayParcelable(adapter.mCheckStates));`

Help will be appreciated. Thank you!

**EDIT**: I had initialized `bundle` wrong. Now I do not get any sort of errors, but the checkbox state isn't saved. I could use some help with that. Thank you!

Comment: Did you debug what's null? `bundle` or `adapter`?

Comment: No. I'm quite new to Android. I did have that question in mind, but didn't know how to find out. Should I set breakpoints and use the debugger?

Comment: Yes. And if adapter is created in parent class, have you passed that object here in this class?

Comment: @MysticMagic Okay, it's the bundle. The bundle is null. On destrpy belongs to the parent class. Why would I have to pass it to `MyAdapter` class? It's a `MyAdapter` object. Please correct me if I'm wrong. Appreciate it.

Comment: Show related code. Where is bundle declared and initialized?

Comment: @MysticMagic the bundle is created and initialized in the parent class.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62872/discussion-between-mysticmagic-and-slay).